# Android : How to fix force close error on registering accelerometer listener?

Tags: android, accelerometer

My problem is my app force close when I want to register `accelerometer listener` in `onResume()`.

I used many tutorials and examples and just did what they said. But still I have this problem.

When I remove this line in onResume() the app doesn't force close anymore but still doesn't work.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

logcat:
thread exiting with uncaught exception java.lang.NullPointerException at net.OSCam.MainActivity.onSensorChanged

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
    Sensor source = arg0.sensor;
    float z = arg0.values[2];

    if(source.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        txtDebug.setText(Float.toString(z));
    }
}
```

Comment: I use API 14 to compile the program.

Comment: Add the logcat, please

Comment: Please refer this link. This helped me in my case. http://androidexample.com/Accelerometer_Basic_Example_-_Detect_Phone_Shake_Motion/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=109&aaid=131

Comment: Please specify which line is the one affected. Is it `Sensor source = arg0.sensor;` or `if(source.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){`, or `txtDebug.setText(Float.toString(z));` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me.
I put the line below in onWindowFocusChanged() function instead of onCreate().

```
txtDebug = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_tv_debug);
```

The function onSensorChanged() runs before onWindowFocusChanged().